# Multiple select filters in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering

i'm learning reactjs. I'm trying to write a code that allows multiple  options to be chosen and then applied. I currently have the code below but it doesn't work as i expected and i don't know why.
I'm also using hooks for this

```js
const [commodityFilter, setCF] = useState('');

const [tradeSideFilter, setTSF] = useState('');

function commoditySearch(rows) {
  const columns = rows[0] && Object.keys(rows[0]);
  return rows.filter((row) =>
    columns.some(
      (column) =>
        row[column]
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(commodityFilter.toLowerCase() > -1 || tradeSideFilter.toLowerCase()) > -1
    )
  );
}
```

The select inputs are:

```js
<select
  className="select-options"
  value={commodityFilter}
  onChange={(e) => setCF(e.target.value)}
>
<select
  className="select-options"
  value={tradeSideFilter}
  onChange={(e) => setTSF(e.target.value)}
>
```

I'm calling the function here

```js
<HistoryTable data={commoditySearch(currentPosts)} />
```

Please what am I doing wrong?